# how to use the MVVM pattern correctly

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0

I do not understand how to correctly use the MVVM pattern, in half the cases the example is presented as in the first, and the rest as in the second. I believe that in the first example, the database is written to and this is not true. Or am I wrong? Can you send a link to an article where the MVVM pattern is used correctly?
1)https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/
2)https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/

Comment: Both links you provided point to the same article.

Comment: As for your question, unfortunately, I did not come across a good article on this topic, designed for beginners. Sharp's learning presupposes first mastering the main OOP patterns "on the console", then OOP application patterns (MVC, MVP). The student begins to study WPF already having a certain amount of knowledge and experience, including the implementation of MVC / MVP. Therefore, in articles on MVVM there are no explanations for beginners.
And the article you mentioned is, in general, a very bad example for MVVM. It rather confuses understanding.

Comment: The link points to a minimal example. There is no database there, no actual code.

Answer (score -1):

showcasing some features of wpf implemented with MVVM

- shortcuts
  -- alt+letter to jump to controls
  -- ctrl+s to save
- validation
  -- implemented as tooltip
- implementing buttons/commands
- propertychanged to update UI

view

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel TextElement.FontSize="25">
        <DockPanel.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="S" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
        </DockPanel.InputBindings>
        <UniformGrid Rows="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Label Content="_Email" Margin="5" Target="{x:Reference EmailTextBox}"/>
            <Label Content="_Location" Margin="5" Target="{x:Reference LocationTextBox}"/>
            <Label Content="Valid from" Margin="5"/>
            <Label Content="Valid to:" Margin="5"/>
            <Label Content="Info" Margin="5"/>
            <Grid/>
        </UniformGrid>
        <UniformGrid Rows="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBox Margin="5" Text="{Binding NewEntry.EMailAddress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="EmailTextBox"/>
            <TextBox Margin="5" Text="{Binding NewEntry.Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="LocationTextBox"/>
            <DatePicker Margin="5" SelectedDate="{Binding NewEntry.ValidFrom, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DatePicker Margin="5" SelectedDate="{Binding NewEntry.ValidTo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Save [Ctrl+S]" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Padding="5"/>
        </UniformGrid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

and viewmodel

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private EntryViewModel _newEntry;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteSave, CanExecuteSave);
        CreateNew();
    }

    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; }

    public EntryViewModel NewEntry
    {
        get { return _newEntry; }
        private set
        {
            if (_newEntry != null)
                _newEntry.PropertyChanged -= NewEntry_PropertyChanged;
            SetValue(ref _newEntry, value);
            if (_newEntry != null)
                _newEntry.PropertyChanged += NewEntry_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void NewEntry_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(EntryViewModel.HasErrors))
            SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EntryViewModel> Entries { get; } = new ObservableCollection<EntryViewModel>();

    private bool CanExecuteSave()
    {
        return !NewEntry.HasErrors;
    }
    private void ExecuteSave()
    {
        Entries.Add(NewEntry);
        CreateNew();
    }

    private void CreateNew()
    {
        NewEntry = new EntryViewModel
        {
            EMailAddress = "me@dummy.com",
            Location = "empty",
            ValidFrom = DateTime.Now,
            ValidTo = DateTime.Now,
        };
    }
}

public class EntryViewModel : NotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _eMailAddress;
    private string _location;
    private DateTime? _validFrom;
    private DateTime? _validTo;

    [EmailAddress]
    public string EMailAddress
    {
        get { return _eMailAddress; }
        set { SetValue(ref _eMailAddress, value); }
    }

    [Required]
    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set { SetValue(ref _location, value); }
    }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(EntryViewModel), nameof(ValidToAfterValidFrom))]
    public DateTime? ValidFrom
    {
        get { return _validFrom; }
        set { SetValue(ref _validFrom, value); }
    }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(EntryViewModel), nameof(ValidToAfterValidFrom))]
    public DateTime? ValidTo
    {
        get { return _validTo; }
        set { SetValue(ref _validTo, value); }
    }

    public static ValidationResult ValidToAfterValidFrom(object _, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var vm = (EntryViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        vm.ClearErrors(nameof(ValidFrom));
        vm.ClearErrors(nameof(ValidTo));
        return vm.ValidFrom < vm.ValidTo ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult("valid from must be before valid to", new[] { nameof(ValidFrom), nameof(ValidTo) });
    }
}
```

and the used base and utility classes

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}

public class NotifyDataErrorInfo : ObservableObject, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, List<string>> _errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public bool HasErrors => _errors.Values.Any(l => l.Count > 0);

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName = null)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
            ? _errors.Values.SelectMany(l => l)
            : _errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var errors) ? errors : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    public string GetAllErrors(string seperator)
    {
        return string.Join(seperator, _errors.Values.SelectMany(l => l));
    }

    protected override void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!Equals(field, value))
        {
            base.SetValue(ref field, value, propertyName);
            Validate(value, propertyName);
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateAndOnPropertyChanged<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        Validate(value, propertyName);
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected virtual void Validate<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var validationresults = new List<ValidationResult>(1);
        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = propertyName }, validationresults))
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>>();
            foreach (var result in validationresults)
            {
                foreach (var name in result.MemberNames)
                {
                    if (!dict.TryGetValue(name, out List<ValidationResult> errorsForProperty))
                        dict.Add(name, errorsForProperty = new List<ValidationResult>());
                    errorsForProperty.Add(result);
                }
            }
            foreach (var pair in dict)
            {
                if (!_errors.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out List<string> propertyErrors))
                    _errors.Add(pair.Key, propertyErrors = new List<string>());
                propertyErrors.Clear();
                propertyErrors.AddRange(validationresults.Select(vr => vr.ErrorMessage));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out List<string> propertyErrors))
                propertyErrors.Clear();
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void ValidateAll()
    {
        foreach (var errors in _errors.Values)
        {
            errors.Clear();
        }

        var validationresults = new List<ValidationResult>(1);
        if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this, null, null), validationresults, true))
        {
            foreach (var result in validationresults)
            {
                foreach (var propertyName in result.MemberNames)
                {
                    if (!_errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out List<string> propertyErrors))
                        _errors.Add(propertyName, propertyErrors = new List<string>());
                    propertyErrors.Add(result.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasErrors));
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
    }

    protected void ClearErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (_errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out List<string> propertyErrors))
            propertyErrors.Clear();
    }
}

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
        _execute.Invoke();
    }
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute();
    }
}
public class DelegateCommand<T> : ObservableObject, ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }
    public void Execute(T parameter)
    {
        _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    }
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute((T)parameter);
    }
}
```